# 'Cannot find name 'html2canvas'.ts(2304)' when library is loaded dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, cdn, html2canvas

I am loading the html2canvas library dynamically in the project like below:

```
const script: any = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/html2canvas@1.3.2/dist/html2canvas.min.js';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script)
```

And the library is getting loaded properly and the element is getting converted to canvas as expected.

But I am getting error in code file for "html2canvas" as
"Cannot find name 'html2canvas'.ts(2304)" when used as below:

```
html2canvas(parentEle, { allowTaint: true }).then((canvas: any) => {
            const image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        });
```

I think the error is of Typescript.

Any idea on how to resolve it?

Thankyou inadvance.

Comment: I have appended it as follows:
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

Comment: So why dynamically? If you do not always need html2canvas, then dynamically load that part too - that of course will stop your linter from linting

Comment: because cannot add it through npm install

Comment: log to check if variable is available.

Comment: Network call to the library is success:
Request URL: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/html2canvas@1.3.2/dist/html2canvas.min.js
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200  (from disk cache)
Remote Address: 151.101.153.229:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin